# Atualização de ListView não funciona

Tags: android, listview, android-adapter

Olá,

Podem ajudar?

Na tela de pesquisa está retornando os dados da pesquisa anterior mais a nova pesquisa realizada. A listView não atualiza somente com os novos resultados do retorno da pesquisa.

Já utilizei o

```
listView.setAdapter(null);

adapter=new SimpleAdapter(EnderecosActivity.this, enderecotList,
                R.layout.list_end,
                new String[] { }, new int[] {});
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
```

Segue código abaixo:

```
package com.example.wander.cadastro;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.support.v7.app.ActionBar;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar;
import android.test.suitebuilder.TestMethod;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ListAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.SimpleAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.w3c.dom.Text;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import cepBr.model.Cep;
import cepBr.service.CepServiceAndroid;

public class EnderecosActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView username;
String cepRetornado;
String logradouroRetornado;
String bairroRetornado;
String localidadeRetornada;
String estadoRetornado;

EditText logradouro;
EditText localidade;
EditText estado;

Bundle bundle;
private ListView listView;
ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> enderecotList;
ListAdapter adapter;
CepServiceAndroid cepServiceAndroid= new CepServiceAndroid();
List<Cep> resultados;
String user=null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_enderecos);
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    Intent intent=getIntent();
    bundle = intent.getExtras();

    user = bundle.getString("username");
    setUser(user);
    enderecotList=new ArrayList<>();
    listView= (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_enderecos);


    Button btn= (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonPesquisar);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            estado= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextUf);
            localidade= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLocalidade);
            logradouro= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextLogradouro);
            String state= estado.getText().toString();
            String city=localidade.getText().toString();
            String place=logradouro.getText().toString();

            getParametros(state,city,place);


            limparForm();
        }
    });

    rediretcView(toolbar);
}



private void rediretcView(Toolbar toolbar) {
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(item -> {
        switch(item.getItemId()){
            case R.id.menu_endereco:
                bundle.putString("username", user);
                recreate();
                return true;

            case R.id.menu_perfil:
                Intent perfil= new Intent(this, UsuarioDetalheActivity.class);
                bundle.putString("username", user);
                perfil.putExtras(bundle);
                startActivity(perfil);
                return true;
        }
        return false;
    });
}

public void validateParams(String state,String city, String place){
    if (state.trim().isEmpty() || city.trim().isEmpty()|| place.trim().isEmpty()){
        Toast.makeText(this, "Todos os campos são obrigatórios", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void getParametros(String state, String city, String place){
    enderecotList=new ArrayList<>();
    //  if(adapter!=null){
    enderecotList.clear();

    adapter=new SimpleAdapter(EnderecosActivity.this, enderecotList,
            R.layout.list_end,
            new String[] { }, new int[] {});
    listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    // }
    validateParams(state,city,place);
    EnderecosHelper enderecosHelper=new EnderecosHelper();
    enderecosHelper.execute(state,city,place);

}

public void limparForm(){
    estado.setText("");
    localidade.setText("");
    logradouro.setText("");
}
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu, menu);
    return true;
}

public void setUser(String user){
    username= (TextView) findViewById(R.id.txtUsername);

    UsuarioDao usuarioDao= new UsuarioDao(this);
    Cursor cursor= usuarioDao.getByEmail(user);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    String name=cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(DataSource.USERNAME));
    username.setText(name);

}

private class EnderecosHelper extends AsyncTask<String,CepServiceAndroid,List<Cep>> {


    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        int quant=listView.getCount();
        String q= String.valueOf(quant);
        Log.i("QUANTIDADE", q);
        if(quant>0) {
            enderecotList=new ArrayList<>();
            Log.i("LIMPANDO",q);
            //enderecotList.clear();
            listView.setAdapter(null);

        }
    }

    @Override
    protected List<Cep> doInBackground(String... params) {
        try {
            resultados=new ArrayList<Cep>();
            resultados= cepServiceAndroid.requestCeps(params[0],params[1],params[2]);

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return resultados;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Cep> results) {
        HashMap<String, String> endereco = null;



            for (Cep resultado:resultados) {
                if(resultado.getStatus().equals("SUCCESS")) {
                    cepRetornado=resultado.getCep();
                    logradouroRetornado=resultado.getLogradouro();
                    bairroRetornado=resultado.getBairro();
                    localidadeRetornada=resultado.getLocalidade();
                    estadoRetornado=resultado.getUf();

                    endereco = new HashMap<>();
                    endereco.put("cep", cepRetornado);
                    endereco.put("logradouro",logradouroRetornado);
                    endereco.put("bairro", bairroRetornado);
                    endereco.put("localidade", localidadeRetornada);
                    endereco.put("estado", estadoRetornado);

                    enderecotList.add(endereco);
                }
                if (resultado.getStatus().equals("NOT_FOUND")){
                    Toast.makeText(EnderecosActivity.this, "CEP não encontrado", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }


        }

        adapter = new SimpleAdapter(EnderecosActivity.this, enderecotList,
                R.layout.list_end,
                new String[] { "cep", "logradouro","bairro", "localidade",
                        "estado"}, new int[] {
                R.id.textCep, R.id.textLogradouro, R.id.textBairro, R.id.textLocalidade,
                R.id.textEstado });

        listView.setAdapter(adapter);


    }


}
```

}

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtUsername"
        android:visibility="invisible"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />

<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<EditText
    android:id="@+id/editTextUf"
    android:layout_width="131dp"
    android:layout_height="45dp"
    android:ems="10"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:hint="UF"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="28dp" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextLocalidade"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="45dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.53"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Localidade"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="153dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="28dp" />
```

```
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/editTextLogradouro"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:hint="Logradouro"
        android:inputType="textPersonName"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="100dp" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/buttonPesquisar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pesquisar"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="2dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="160dp" />

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/list_enderecos"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="60mm"
        android:layout_weight="2">


    </ListView>
```

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textCep"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorAccent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLogradouro"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#5d5d5d"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textBairro"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textLocalidade"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textEstado"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:paddingBottom="2dip"
    android:paddingTop="6dip"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:textSize="16sp"
    android:textStyle="bold" />
```

Comment: Você tem que usar o método `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()`;  para verificar se houve alguma mudança na lista.

Comment: Então, está função não compila, nem mesmo é disponibilizada pelo Intelij. As que aparecem são _itálico_ notify() _itálico_ e  _itálico_ notifyAll() _itálico_

Comment: Pesquisando achei um local que informa que não é possível implemento o 
`adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`  diretamente dessa forma customizei um adapter porém continua a aplicação do `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); ` não teve nenhum efeito.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tenta fazer isso ó:

```
    // ...
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(List<Cep> results) {
        HashMap<String, String> endereco = null;
        // ...
    }

    adapter = new SimpleAdapter(EnderecosActivity.this, enderecotList,
        R.layout.list_end,
        new String[] { "cep", "logradouro","bairro", "localidade",
                    "estado"}, new int[] {
        R.id.textCep, R.id.textLogradouro, R.id.textBairro, R.id.textLocalidade,
        R.id.textEstado });
        listView.setAdapter(null); 
        listView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
// ...
```

ou então criar seu proprio adapter onde voce pode ter maior controle sobre o seu mecanismo.

Uma coisa que fiquei sem saber do porque, foi isso: `{R.id.textCep, R.id.textLogradouro, R.id.textBairro, R.id.textLocalidade, R.id.textEstado }`, ou seja, no meu entender voce teria que passar aqui, os valores do set do seu "map".

se der problema avisa que a gente reve juntos.